# In what cases can there be such a situation when unit tests will run earlier than View is fully loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, unit-testing, nsrunloop

I was stumbled upon `RunLoop.current.run(until: Date())` string in ViewController unit testing tutorial.
In article the author wrote: “ *The RunLoop.current.run(until: Date()) statement makes sure the run loop associated with the current thread has ample time to let the drawing operations to complete.*”

Here the code:

```
class CreateOrderViewControllerTests: XCTestCase
{
 // MARK: - Subject under test

 var sut: CreateOrderViewController!
 var window: UIWindow!

 // MARK: - Test lifecycle

 override func setUp()
 {
   super.setUp()
   window = UIWindow()
   setupCreateOrderViewController()
   loadView()
 }

override func tearDown()
{
   window = nil
   super.tearDown()
}

// MARK: - Test setup

func setupCreateOrderViewController()
{
  let bundle = Bundle.main
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateOrderViewController") as? CreateOrderViewController
}

func loadView()
{
    window.addSubview(sut.view)  
    RunLoop.current.run(until:Date())
}

func testCursorFocusShouldMoveToNextTextFieldWhenUserTapsReturnKey()
{
// Given


// Scroll to the top of table view so the first text field is visible and can actually become first responder
let firstSectionIndex = 0
let firstRowIndex = 0
sut.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: firstRowIndex, section: firstSectionIndex), at: .bottom, animated: false)

// When
let currentTextField = sut.textFields[0]
let nextTextField = sut.textFields[1]
currentTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
_ = sut.textFieldShouldReturn(currentTextField)

// Then
XCTAssert(!currentTextField.isFirstResponder, "Current text field should lose keyboard focus")

XCTAssert(nextTextField.isFirstResponder, "Next text field should gain keyboard focus")
}
```

I read a few articles about RunLoop, and tried to replace   `RunLoop.current.run(until:Date())` with
`RunLoop.current.run(until:Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30))`. [image]
and saw that all 30 seconds xcode did not proceed to the next process.

Then I conducted experiment with assigning view to window on background concurrent thread with `RunLoop.current.run(until:Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 30))`.[image]
It also didn’t call any other processes on any threads for 30 seconds, that is, the system waited 30 seconds and at that time the process that was already running, it was being finalized, and again any other processes on any threads haven't been called for 30 seconds.

Then I looked on what thread the viewController initialization and window.addSubview() processes are running - it is **`Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)`**, then I looked on what thread test functions are running this is also **`Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)`**. Due to it is serial it is impossible that test functions is executing before viewController initialization and window.addSubview() processes are done. But some people wrote that it could be, when and why?

Comment: This is not relevant to your question, but the code you are showing, whether it comes from the tutorial or is yours (can't tell) is deeply flawed. Code that needs a view controller to act as a real view controller, to load something from the storyboard, to add a subview, etc., is _not a unit test_. It is a UI test. Trying to jam that sort of activity into a unit test is completely wrong. A unit test shouldn't have to wait for _anything_ interface-related to happen; it should be about testing a tiny sliver of logic, only.

Comment: why did you delete previous your comment with my reply and wrote same comment again?View controllers and views can and should be unit tested. This contributes to the app quality a lot since view controllers make up a large part of the codebase.
As long as we design view controllers with testability in mind, testing them is no different from the model objects. In order to do this, we must make UIViewController passive and practice dependency injection. Moreover, unit tests must verify the content and not the layout. + https://qualitycoding.org/testing-view-controllers/

Comment: using the application window during testing might seem a little odd at first, I want to stress that in large and complex apps, the ability to quickly launch, view and interact with a specific screen cannot be understated.

Comment: I didn't delete any comment. You've said this twice but it's not true; it didn't happen. And if I did delete my own comment, it is not correct to "tell" me not to. And calling a comment "useless" is also not correct. Please try to stick to relevant comments about the question: personal remarks, bossing other users or passing judgment on them, are not valid on the Stack Exchange forums.

Comment: "in large and complex apps, the ability to quickly launch, view and interact with a specific screen cannot be understated" This is absolutely true! And that is why there are _UI tests_, which allow you to do that. Unit tests do _not_ allow you to do that, and one should not try to bend a unit test to do it. — The way to test whether dependency injection works as expected is through the use of mocks, not by launching the real app, running it, and looking inside it to see what got injected.

Comment: @matt excuse me for violating comment rules, but isn't it useless? If your word are completely true in ALL situation ,can you prove your statement to bring at least some benefit for readers?